# Get the file that modified most of times between two commits in Git

Tags: git, shell, powershell

Recently, I found the project that I am working on has way more bugs than I expected, and I would like to find out which files are changed most during our sprint.

I can do something like this, but it only shows what files are changed, but does not show me how many times they have been changed

```
git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2
```

Please put me in the right direction to write a script to show what files changed most of times between two commits.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean like changed number of lines?

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --name-only --format=%n SHA1..SHA2 | Group-Object | Format-Table Count,Name
```

Use `--format=%n` to get a blank line for each commit to collapse them all into one sorted and counted entry. Then the file names for each collate together in `Group-Object`.

Powershell translation of `| sort | uniq -c` from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timid/archive/2009/08/20/powershell-one-liner-sort-uniq-c.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

From the [git-diff documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) you'll need either `--stat` or `--numstat` depending on how you want the output to look:

```
  git diff --stat hash1 hash2

  .file1.un~ | Bin 0 -> 948 bytes
  .file2.un~ | Bin 0 -> 523 bytes
  file1      |  25 +++++++++++++++++++++++++
  file2      |   8 ++++++++
  4 files changed, 33 insertions(+)
```

Or

```
 git diff --numstat hash1 hash2

 -       -       .file1.un~
 -       -       .file2.un~
 25      0       file1
 8       0       file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for last 10 commits. Feel free to change it for you needs. If you encounter more than 2-digit occurrences change the `sprintf` expression, `"%02d"`, accordingly.

```
git log --name-only --pretty="%n" HEAD~10..HEAD |
egrep '.' |
sort |
uniq -c  |
perl -pe 's/([0-9]+)/sprintf("%02d",$1)/e' |
sort -r |
less
```